# Arduino program not incrementing loop counter

Tags: arduino

I am programming effects for an LED cube. The cube and the independent functions are working correctly. The problem occurs when I call `turnon_layer` function in a loop. The loop counter is not incremented.

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  Serial.println(i);
  turnon_layer(1000,i);
}
```

The Serial monitor shows that `i` has a constant value of 0 throughout.

When I call the functions with constants, then the output is as expected.

```
turnon_layer(1000,0);
turnon_layer(1000,1);
turnon_layer(1000,2);
turnon_layer(1000,3);
```

My turnon_layer function is :

```
void turnon_layer(long time, int layer)
{
  boolean state = HIGH;
  long wait, start = millis();
  for(i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
      if(i!=layer) digitalWrite(levelPin[i], !LOW);
      else digitalWrite(levelPin[i], !HIGH);
  }

  if(time/2<10)  wait = time/2;
  else  wait = 10;

  while(millis()-start<time)
  {
    state = !state;
    //Serial.println(state);
    //First 8 LEDs
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    digitalWrite(ledPin[i][j],state);

    //Next 8 LEDs
    for(i=2;i<4;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    digitalWrite(ledPin[i][j],!state);
    delay(wait);
  }
}
```

I am using the Arduino IDE.

What is going wrong ? Why ?

Comment: Are you able to post the entire code including the `setup()` and `void()` methods as well as any variable declarations at the top?

Comment: @Marko: Did you mean `setup()` and `loop()`?

Comment: @DaveTweed I did indeed, all these vibrations on the bus are messing with my brain :)

Comment: @Marko Perhaps not a properly terminated bus - did you catch it at the terminal? :-)

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Now I definitely look mentally challenged laughing at my laptop. Thanks for that.

Comment: Just a tip, not related to this problem, Never use single letter Variables like "i", "j","k". Use "loopCnt", "count", "cnt" instead!

Comment: @Swanand do you have anything concrete to back that statement? A quick scan at the [Wikipedia For Loop Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) reveals that just about every example uses `i`.

Comment: @Marko He is just developing on the programming practise of having variables with meaningful names.

Comment: But `i` means a lot to me ;) No pun intended.

Comment: @Marko As AshRj said, it's about good programming practise. Imagine, You need to search for a variable "i"... Ctrl+F, "i"... It will give you results of "i"nt and wh"i"le too! So, IMHO, at least use "ii" :)

Comment: @Swanand That's one piece of attempted advice that I find amusing and pointless: Go scan example code across languages, spanning all levels of expertise, then let's discuss how often that "i" is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the variable `i` declared as a *global* variable? i.e. at the top of the file outside all methods?

It may be getting overwritten by the loop inside your `turnon_layer()` method.

To test, just change the variable to letter `k` inside just one of your loops.

Comment: The experiment you're proposing will fail, because `j` is also used in the called function. In general, loop index variables should pretty much always be declared local to each function in which they're used.

Comment: Agreed, I have seen Arduino examples where `i` is declared with other variables at the top of the file. Generally bad practice.

Comment: @DaveTweed I saw your update and have updated it to letter `k`.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Making it a local solved the problem.

Comment: @DaveTweed I just had another look and I believe that unless `j` was declared at the top it wouldn't interfere because when specified in the loop declaration it becomes a local variable to that loop body.